# Azure Function App - Azure DevOps pipeline deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I am testing Azure Powershell Function Apps. I used Azure DEvOps pipeline to upload Function files into Azure Function App, pipeline completed successfully, I can see both files, run.ps1 and function.json i my Function App main blade Function/App Files. My files below:

run.ps1

```
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Timer)

# Get the current universal time in the default string format.
$currentUTCtime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

# The 'IsPastDue' property is 'true' when the current function invocation is later than scheduled.
if ($Timer.IsPastDue) {
    Write-Host "PowerShell timer is running late!"
}

# Write an information log with the current time.
Write-Host "PowerShell timer trigger function ran! TIME: $currentUTCtime"
```

function.json

```
{
    "bindings": [
      {
        "name": "Timer",
        "type": "timerTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "schedule": "* * * * * *"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I am not sure how to Create a Function based on these files, When I go to `Overview` I don't see any functions in `Functions` tab. There is no option to create a function using option `Develop in Portal`. I didn't find any useful info in MS documentation. Earlier when I was using `Develop in the Portal` option and I was able to create Function Apps manually from the portal. Now when I am using Azure DevOps pipelines to upload Function files (run.ps1, function.json) to Azure Function App, I am not sure what is recommended way to create Functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When we create the Azure Function App, it shows the option to create and develop in Azure Portal:

[image]

2. Created PowerShell Core Timer Trigger Azure Function App in VS Code and pushed the code to the Azure DevOps Repository using git commands:

[image]

3. Click on “**Set up build**”
4. It takes you to pipeline Job step where repos and branch is automatically selected. Then Select the option shown below:

[image]

It will ask you to select Subscription, Function App created on Azure Portal.

***Below is the YAML Code of the pipeline created automatically*** :

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:
azureSubscription: '<subscription_id>'

functionAppName: 'dkazfnapp-ci-101'

vmImageName: 'windows-2019'

workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/'

stages:
- stage: Build
displayName: Build stage 

jobs:
- job: Build
displayName: Build
pool:
vmImage: $(vmImageName)

steps:
- powershell: |
if (Test-Path "extensions.csproj") {
dotnet build extensions.csproj --output ./$(workingDirectory)/bin
}
displayName: 'Build extensions' 

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
displayName: 'Archive files'

inputs:
rootFolderOrFile: $(workingDirectory)
includeRootFolder: false
archiveType: zip
archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
replaceExistingArchive: true

- publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
displayName: Deploy stage
dependsOn: Build
condition: succeeded()

jobs:
- deployment: Deploy
displayName: Deploy
environment: $(functionAppName)
pool:
vmImage: $(vmImageName)

strategy:
runOnce:
deploy:

steps:
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
inputs:
azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
appType: functionApp
appName: $(functionAppName)
package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

For more information on pipeline  customization, refer to this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=csharp,yaml&pivots=v1).

**Save and Run** the pipeline.

5. **Build Succeeded** and asking to grant the permission for deploy:
   [image]

Click on “***View***” and “***Permit***” for deploy the function app.
6. **Deploy Succeeded**:

[image]

**Result**:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works, I had incorrect function file structure, Thanks a lot!